# How to make .htaccess redirect to subdomain with parameters

Tags: .htaccess

How do I make a redirect from all pages following `/react-api`, such as:

```
www.example.com/react-api/workout?id=123
www.example.com/react-api/another-site/?id=321
```

to:

```
app.example.com/react-api
```

and I wan't to keep the folder and parameters.

This is what I have tried:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^react-api/(.*) app.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But it doesn't work.

Please help

Comment: what do you mean anubhava? can you show me what you mean please

Comment: they should be redirected to `app.example.com`, I've highligted the url now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `http://` in your target URL and also change order of your rules and keep redirect rule at the top:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^react-api(/.*)?$ http://app.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answer! however, it redirects me to app.example.com, without the folders and parameters